# Laravel is not reading environmental variables on AWS Lambda

Tags: php, laravel-5, aws-lambda

Laravel deployment on AWS Lambda using bref/serverless.

Error message:

```
production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL:...
```

This is a database connection error but I think this is because Laravel is not reading environmental variables.

This:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return env('APP_NAME');
});
```

returns nothing although APP_NAME is set and works properly on a local computer.

I'm not sure where the .env file is located on AWS Lambda and how to check it (other than the test above) if it is properly transferred to AWS Lambda.

Comment: On Lambda the environment variables are part of the function definition so you should make sure the task you are using to publish to Lambda transfers the variables from `.env` to the Lambda function or use `php artisan config:cache` before deploying to generate a cached config file and then use only `config` entries

Comment: thanks @apokryfos Caching the config was a good idea but now I don't know why lambda can't see views "View [welcome] not found." :(

Comment: It doesn't look like lambda is reading .env file despite the fact that in serverless.yml I have added useDotenv: true, when I config:cache most env variables are ok but it caches local views directory that doesn't work on lambda so I don't think caching is an option

Comment: I am having the same issue where php cannot find my env vars set on the lambda function.
Did anyone find a solution?